# How to initiate a view with the ScrollView in the bottom in Swift ui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building a chat application in Swift UI and when I am in the *"ChatView"* I want to see the last messages written, so when the messages are over the screen ([finalView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE3Qa.png)) I need to put the scroll of the view in the bottom.

This is the code I'm using:

```swift
ScrollView {
  ForEach(self.userController.userMessage.identified(by: \.self)) { message in
    if message.from == UserService.currentUserID! {
      HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text(message.message)
          .bold()
          .foregroundColor(Color.white)
          .padding(8)
          .background(Color.blue, cornerRadius: 8)
      }
    } else {
      HStack {
        Text(message.message)
          .bold()
          .foregroundColor(Color.white)
          .padding(8)
          .background(Color.gray, cornerRadius: 8)
        Spacer()
     }
     .offset(y: 8)
   }
  }
 }
}
```

How can I put always the ScrollView in the bottom per default?

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this since `ScrollView` doesn't support programatic scrolling (yet? ever?) was to rotate and flip it.

```
ScrollView{
    VStack{
        ForEach(items ) { item in
            Text(item.text)
              .rotationEffect(.pi) // rotate each item
              .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center) // and flip it so we can flip the container to keep the scroll indicators on the right
        }
    }
}
.rotationEffect(.pi) // rotate the whole ScrollView 180º
.scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center) // flip it so the indicator is on the right
```

Comment: iOS 14 will support programmatic scrolling

Comment: Worth noting, whilst this works, it's not ideal. It presents a problem if using within a sheet (for example), where swiping up beyond the content of the ScrollView will pull the sheet down to dismiss, as it thinks this is the top of the view (when it's actually the bottom).